# how to get value from functional expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, func

Can anyone guide me in getting the value from functional expression? Below is the func expression which I am passing to the method . I will require the value in the method below

```
 Expression<Func<T, bool>> conditionalProperty
```

- Method

  ```
  public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> RequiredForBeneficiaryWhen<T, TProperty>(
      this IRuleBuilder<T, TProperty> ruleBuilder, Expression<Func<T, bool>> conditionalProperty)
  {
      var conditionalPropertyName = new ExpressionHandler().GetFullPropertyName(conditionalProperty);


      var validationrule = new UnobtrusiveValidationRule()
      {
          ValidationType = "mvfbenefreq",
          Parameterlist = new Dictionary<string, string>
          {
              { "conditionalproperty1", conditionalPropertyName },
              { "conditionalproperty2", "false" }
          }
      };

      return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new BeneficiaryRequiredValidation<T>(conditionalProperty, false,validationrule));

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
var func=conditionalProperty.Compile()
func(obj);
```

Comment: Could you explain this func(obj)?